# MongoDb Connection Failure in Openshift Bottle App

Tags: python, mongodb, database-connection, openshift, bottle

I've been trying to host bottle app in openshift. My app uses MongoDb and have written the wsgi application file to load `virtenv/venv/bin/activate_this.py` and loading PY_CACHE folder.

It fails to connect to MongoDb.

```
pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I've the following code:

```
PY_DIR = os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR'], "python")
virtenv = PY_DIR + '/virtenv/'
PY_CACHE = os.path.join(virtenv, 'lib', 
                     'python' + os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_VERSION'],
                     'site-packages')

# I've concatenated python-version as thats the directory available.
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = os.path.join(PY_CACHE)
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')

try:
# Updated exec as python version 3.3
    exec(compile(open(virtualenv).read(), virtualenv, 'exec'), dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass

from my_app import application # for mod_wsgi
```

- I am not sure about the right locations to refer, as its available in multiple folders.
- Do i need to create venv mandatory?
- What is the folder heirarchy?

I've taken reference from this [git-repository wsgi file](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/bottle-openshift-quickstart/blob/master/wsgi/application)
The same issue occurs when i ssh to machine and run the python file directly.

Comment: What is the code for connecting to mongodb?

Comment: `uri = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL']
coll = MongoClient(uri).db.coll`

Comment: Feel free to add the script of your database connection to the question